# can't navigate to different screen using react-native-drawer with react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using `react-native-router-flux` for the Navigation system and using `react-native-drawer` for the sidebar. If an user clicks on menu item which is in the sidebar, I want to redirect user to different screen and close the Drawer. I'm using the following code snippets.

`Actions.refresh({key: 'drawer', open: false})` to Close the Drawer

`Actions.pageTwo.call()` to Open the Second Page

Both are working without any problem if I'm using it in separate functions. But, If I trigger both the snippets from the same function. It is not working.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? Does your app have any significant lags between screen transitions?

Comment: I didn't find the solution for that. Please Let me know if you find the solution. 

Thanks,

Comment: Just now tried @steven's Solution. It is working for my use case. I marked it as correct solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this scenario working for me with both libraries.  At a high level I create a custom component to render the content of react-native-drawer which I pass a function to responsible for closing the drawer.  Then when I press one of the drawer items I fire both a react-native-router-flux navigation action (in my case a PUSH) and I call the function passed in to close the drawer.

Here is what defining my drawer looks like. Remember DrawerNavigationConten is ultimately just a ListView or whatever implementation you prefer to render the drawer content.

```
class RootComponent extends Component {
  ...

  closeDrawer() {
    this.drawerRef.closeDrawer();
  }

  render() {
    const drawerNavigationContent = (
      <DrawerNavigationContent
        closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer.bind(this)}
      />
    );

    return <Drawer
      ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
      content={drawerNavigationContent}
      ...
      >
      ...here I define my react-native-router-flux scenes...
      </Drawer>
    );
  }
  ...
}
```

Here are the important items in DrawerNavigationContent

```
  import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

  class DrawerNavigationContent extends Component {
    ...

    navigate(location) {
      Actions[location]();
      this.props.closeDrawer();
    }

    ...

    render() {
      ...
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.navigate(...some dynamic scene key...)}>
        ...
      </TouchableOpacity>
      ...
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with `react-native-router-flux` and had some issues with the drawer as well. If both scenes are children of the Drawer like so

`<Scene key="navigationDrawer" component={NavigationDrawer}>
  <Scene key="pageOne" component={PageOne}/>
  <Scene key="pageTwo" component={PageTwo}/>
</Scene>`

you can use `Actions.pageTwo({key: 'navigationDrawer', open: false})` which should close the drawer upon navigation.

Otherwise you could use `Actions.refresh({key: 'navigationDrawer', open: false)` on PageTwo's `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` methods.